# Overriden route id field is being reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

In one of my models i have a field called `token`, that is created with `before_create`. It is never modified again.

In `routes.rb` i am using it instead of id, like: `resources :model, param: :token`

So for example the `edit` route is now `model/:token/edit`.

In my actions i am doing `find_by(:token, params[:token])`.

I have a partial form created with `simple_form` which is being loaded in the `new` and `edit` actions.

This works fine, the routes are generated properly, all showing `:token:` instead of `:id`.

The `show` action works fine. In the show page i have a `link_to` which links to the edit view. This works fine also.

Both are using `:token` in the route, the edit view loads the models fields, everything is normal.

However when you look at the source code for the edit view, it shows the action as `/model/<id>`, instead of `/model/<token>`. For example `/model/5`.

When you submit the edit form, it tries to go to `/model/5/`.

In addition, when i checked the params being sent, it shows `token` set to the value of `id`. So somehow, the `token` field has been reset.

So

1) The `token` field is somehow being reset to the value of `id`. I have no idea how this is happening.

2) `simple_form` seems to be generating the action based off of `id` instead of `token`. However i have realized that since `token` is being reset, it could be that `simple_form` isnt doing anything wrong and is using the value of `token`.

The only fix i could come up with, was setting the `url` field in `simple_form_for` manually, but if i do that, it then breaks the `new` action.

For `simple_form` I'm just doing:

`<%= simple_form_for @model do |f| %>`

In `routes.rb` I'm doing:

```
resources :model, param: :token
```

In the controller, the `edit` action is:

```
@model = Model.find_by(token: params[:token])
```

The `update` action is:

```
@model = Model.find_by(token: params[:token])
if @mode.update model_params
  redirect_to model_path @model.token
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

Nothing fancy in the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `simple_form` uses the default behavior of Rails when generating the route string for you. Since the `config/routes.rb` just provide the named pattern matching for the **Outside In** URL, so it is not too much meaning for the application from inside. For ex, with a route like this

```
model/:token/edit
```

just means any string between `model/` and `/edit` will be assigned to `params[:token]`. It doesn't mean that string has to be the value of `YourModel#token`. Of course, you can assign that pattern to `params[:foobar]` by the same way without breaking anything `model/:foobar/edit`

For fully replace `id` key by `token` key, you have to override the method `YourModel#to_param`

```
# app/models/your_model.rb
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    token
  end
end
```

So that, the `ActiveSupport` will know to use `token` as the value when generating routing pattern from inside out.

You can read more about it at the [Rails's Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#to-param)

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much. I havnt seen this documented anywhere.

Comment: @m5tt I added the reference document in case you want to understand more about it. Happy hacking!

Comment: @yeum1vannam I would never have thought to look there. I feel like maybe something about should be mentioned in the routing guide where it talks about the `param` option. Because i suspected i was not overriding `id` properly, but i couldnt find anything else other then to set that `param` option. Thanks again.